# laravel routing, view not found

Tags: laravel

when am adding, it records saves to database, but when return to view is says ($store_id is undefined)

> Blade:

```
<form action="{{ route("machine-slots.create", $machineSlotId) }}" method="POST">
                            @csrf                        
                            <input type="hidden" name="store_id" value="{{ $store_id }}">    
                            <div class="modal-body ct-modal-form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="slot_id" class=" form-control-label">Slot ID</label>
                                    <input type="number" id="slot" name="slot_id"
                                        placeholder="Enter Slot ID" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group ct-form-dropdown">
                                    <label for="assign-item" class="form-control-label">Assign Item</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="product_id">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Items</option>
                                        @forelse ($products as $i => $product)
                                            <option value={{$product->id}}>{{$product->name}}</option>
                                        @empty

                                        @endforelse
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="quantity" class=" form-control-label">Quantity</label>
                                    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="current_count"
                                        placeholder="Enter Quantity" class="form-control"
                                        onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="max-quantity" class=" form-control-label">Max Quantity</label>
                                    <input type="number" id="max-quantity" name="max_count"
                                        placeholder="Enter Max Quantity" class="form-control"
                                        onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{ $machineSlotId }}" name="machine_address_id">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

> Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request, $machineSlotId)
    {          

        //get all machineslot data
        $machineSlots = $this->getMachineSlotData1($machineSlotId);
        $products = $this->getProductsData();
        $store_id = Machine::where([Machine::COLUMN_MACHINE_ADDRESS_ID => $machineSlotId])->first(['store_id'])->store_id;         
        if($request->input('current_count') > $request->input('max_count'))
        {
            //display text
            Session::flash('warning', "Quantity cannot be higher than max Quantity. Please Try again");   
            //display return
            return view('machine-slots', compact('machineSlotId', 'machineSlots', 'products', 'store_id'));                        
        }
        else 
        {                        
            //create new record
            MachineSlot::create($request->all());            
            //display text
            Session::flash('success', "Table has been updated.");
            //display return
            //return view('machine-slots', compact('machineSlotId', 'machineSlots', 'products', 'store_id'));
            return redirect()->route('machine-slots.index')->with(compact('machineSlotId', 'machineSlots', 'products', 'store_id'));            
        }
    }
```

> Web:
> `
> Route::post('/machine-slots/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\UI\MachineSlotController::class, 'store'])->name('machine-slots.create');

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV49X.png)

Comment: Please, add a better explanation what is  happening

Comment: when am adding new record, it saves to the database, but error says view is not found, even when my view is existing

Comment: Don't worry. I recommend you use the code style in your question instead using images of your code. It'll help to anyone who wants to help

Comment: there, sorry hahahahaha.

Comment: Print or dd store_id before you send to view

Answer (score 0):

Heres the Update:

> Blade

```
no Changes
```

> Controller: Add on Index

```
public function index()
    {        
        //check user Data
        if(Auth::user() != null)
        {
            //get user ID
            $userID = User::findOrFail(auth()->user()->id)->first(['id'])->id;
            //check store is existing, based of passed ID
            $isStoreExisting = Store::where('user_id', $userID)->first(['id'])->id;
            //check machine is Existing, based on passed ID
            $isMachineExisting = Machine::where('store_id', $isStoreExisting)->first(['machine_address_id'])->machine_address_id;
            //get machine data
            $machineSlot = MachineSlot::where('machine_address_id', $isMachineExisting)->first();
            $machineSlots = MachineSlot::where('machine_address_id', $isMachineExisting)->paginate(5);
            //fix paginate error
            return view('machine-slots',compact('machineSlot', 'machineSlots'));
        }
    }

public function store(Request $request, $machineSlotId)
    {          
        //get all machineslot data
        $machineSlots = $this->getMachineSlotData1($machineSlotId);
        $products = $this->getProductsData();
        $store_id = Machine::where([Machine::COLUMN_MACHINE_ADDRESS_ID => $machineSlotId])->first(['store_id'])->store_id;         
        if($request->input('current_count') > $request->input('max_count'))
        {

            //display text
            Session::flash('warning', "Quantity cannot be higher than max Quantity. Please Try again");   
            //display return
            return view('machine-slots', compact('machineSlotId', 'machineSlots', 'products', 'store_id'));             
        }
        else 
        {                        
            //create new record
            MachineSlot::create($request->all());            
            //display text
            Session::flash('success', "Table has been updated.");
            //display return
            return view('machine-slots', compact('machineSlotId', 'machineSlots', 'products', 'store_id'));
        }                
    }
```

> Error: Data duplicates every time i refresh the page